Are "very alone" and "very much alone" interchangeable?
Are "very alone" and "very much alone" used interchangeably?
If not, when to use one and when the other?

britannica.com:
(1) He felt very alone when he went away to school.
my variant:
(2) He felt very much alone when he went away to school.
Is (2) correct?
If not, then why not?

"Extra Examples" on oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:
(3) I felt vulnerable and very much alone.
my variant:
(4) I felt vulnerable and very alone.
Is (4) correct?
If not, then why not?

Both of them are correct, but I feel a small difference between the two:

“He felt very much alone” seems to intensify the certainty he felt of being alone.
“He felt very alone” seems to intensify how alone he felt.

For example, imagine that someone asks you “Was the coffee the right temperature?”

“No, the coffee was very hot.” (The coffee was too hot.)
“No, the coffee was very much hot.” (I ordered iced coffee, but they gave me hot coffee.)

Sometimes only “very much” is appropriate. We can say “X is very much the case,” meaning that X is definitely the case: we are certain that X is true. However, we can’t say “X is very the case.”

The coffee was very much hot   sounds very much strange to me.

Hm, to me it just sounds pompous and old-fashioned. I can still imagine someone saying it: the emphasis would have to go on the word “hot,” and the speaker would have to be annoyed.

@TimR, yes, in that context I would say only "No, the coffee was hot."

Someone can be very much in love ✅ but a person cannot be very much tall ❌

Google ngram shows no results for very much hot compared to very hot and extremely hot

Someone can be very much in love ✅ but to be very in love is far less common, at least in print.

Google ngram shows in 2013 the percentages for very much in love and very in love  were 0.00000036111% and 0.0000165025% respectively, approximately a difference of 4470%. As a result, this proves the first expression is far more idiomatic than the second.

But if we compare the percentage of hits for very alone (0.0000105309%) and very much alone (0.0000060132%) in 2013, the situation is reversed. Approximately, the difference between the two is reduced to 75%.  This data tells us that both expressions are idiomatic and used frequently in print.
Does this mean the two are interchangeable? I would argue it is not because "very much alone" expresses a greater level of intensity, and hints at someone who feels isolated and perhaps abandoned by everyone whereas "very alone" is more likely to express a sentiment of loneliness.

I might say that when this action was first taken against us, that our company felt very much alone in a very big fight, and that we were fighting a lost cause, and that we saw very little light until this committee started action, and many of the things were brought to light […].
Source: Hearings–Volume 10 Congress. Senate. Select Committee on Improper Activities in the Labor or Management Field (1957)

